# how to adjust a replacement list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list of replacement rules:

```
{{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1}
```

What I need is `{{2,15}->1, {2,2}->2}` (because  `{2,2}->1` appears twice in the original list).

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[lst]` or `Union[lst]`  (there should be 8 more ways to do this :)

Comment: But I need the new list to contain {2,2}->2.

Comment: oh sorry, I misread that because you said _{2,2}->1 appears twice_. Ok. So you want the rhs of the rule to be the number of times the lhs of the rule appears then. OK.  I understand now.

Comment: To the author of the OP: in light of the two solutions and some ambiguities that arose can you updated your question and let us know if @Nasser understood your goal right or wrong? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} ->
     3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3};
result1 = Tally[rules]
f[a_ -> b_, c_] := a -> c
result2 = f @@@ result1
```

> `{{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 5}`

Comment: well, I was not expecting anything less than spectacular. Out of curiosity, there is some inherent ambiguity to the phrasing of the OP or am I the only one who got confused?

Comment: @bmf  I am also don't understand the OP, maybe this is a  XY problem.

Comment: thanks for that cvgmt. By the way, for your conformal mapping answer, I still have not managed to place in a nicer way the dynamic text -I mean other than the one I posted as a comment. Did you come up with anything?

Comment: @bmf In this forum,@kglr familiar with this, I think I can learn somthing from his answer.

Comment: well, @kglr seems to be able to do pretty much anything with Mathematica. I am expecting some kglr code that will make us breakfast :-) But I am not sure about which answer you're talking. No kglr responses here, or in the conformal mapping question

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html), using [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) as the combiner function:

```
rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1};
Merge[rules, Total]
(* <|{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2|> *)
```

(edit) If you don't want to merge the rules, but just count them by their left-hand-sides, then use [`CountsBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountsBy.html):

```
rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 3, 
     {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3};
CountsBy[rules, First]
(* <|{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 5|> *)
```

Comment: it was a (+1) from me and still is. Just a warning: With `rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 4};` I obtain `<|{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 10|>` which is not right according to the OP.

Comment: I think the OP was pretty vague about what they want

Comment: I agree, and there seems to be some confusion if you check the discussion under the other solution. I am stating it here for completeness: my understanding was the same as @Nasser had *So you want the rhs of the rule to be the number of times the lhs of the rule appears then*. Anyway, I did not mean offend you, just commented an observation.

Answer (score 3):

```
rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1};
f = If[Length@# == 1, First@#, #[[1, 1]] -> Length[#]] &;
f /@ Gather[rules]
(* {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2} *)
```

Comment: (+1) from me with a friendly warning and suggestion. It breaks down for example for the list `rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 2};` Suggestion something like: `f = If[Length@# == 1, First@#, #[[1, 1]] -> Plus @@ Last /@ #] &; f /@ Gather[rules]` seems to work in a stable way.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if I missed something. The rule you sent works fine in my PC.

Comment: To understand the difference between your code and what I send is to spot the change: you have `#[[1, 1]] -> Length[#]` and I am suggesting `#[[1, 1]] -> Plus @@ Last /@ #`. The rest was inspired from your solution and is the same. Perhaps you can update your post and make it work when there are more than one duplicated rules in the list :-) Nicely done!!!

Comment: @bmf I think you and me understood the question differently. The OP said  `what I need is {{2,15}->1, {2,2}->2} (because {2,2}->1 appears twice in the original list)` so I guessed they want to replace by the number of duplicates instead of the sum of last elements in the rules.

Comment: I think I understood the OP. Let me argue to make my case. Let's say that you have two duplicates, one appears twice and the other three times. The list of rules is `rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3};` If you run `f /@ Gather[rules]` with `f` defined from my comment above you get: `{{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 9}` Then you can also try `rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 4};` and again `f /@ Gather[rules]` gives `{{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 6, {3, 3} -> 4}`.

Comment: In my opinion your method is fine, up to the small amendment I suggested. As far as I see, it produces the right result in various cases.

Comment: @bmf from the OP question if you have this rule `rules = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 3};` I understood that the result should be
`result1 = {{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3}; ` because  `{2, 2} -> 1` duplicates twice and `{3, 3} -> 3}` duplicate three times and with the second rules the result would be `{{2, 15} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 4}`.

Comment: Oh that's also another possible scenario. I understood what @Nasser wrote under the OP: *So you want the rhs of the rule to be the number of times the lhs of the rule appears then*

Comment: @bmf also feel free if you have any suggestion I'm happy for any constructive criticism, suggestion.

Comment: I made a comment under the OP asking for some clarifications. Hope that the author will update soon. If you see that I had a correct understanding, please feel free to update your reply. After all, I just made a minor edit based on your code and what I understood from the question